# SQL query not outputting the correct information

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a query that returns the child id, child title, parent id, and parent title for the highest ranked child in each parent.

So, for example, let's say I have a series of books titled Novels, and then a subset called English Language Novels, and then a subset of that called English Language Novels of the 20th Century.

I want to write a query that would show me the last entry in English Language Novels of the 20th Century (let's say that's the 10th title out of 10 titles), its title, id, parent id, and parent title (English Language Novels).

The problem I'm having is that while I get the correct parent title and parent id when I use max(rank), I don't get the correct child id or title.

Here's my code:

```
select 
    c.child_book_title_id as 'child ID', 
    btn2.text 'Child Title',
    max(c.rank) as 'Last Episode/Season Number',
    c.parent_book_title_id as 'parent ID',
    btn.text 'Parent Title'
from 
    container_associations c
inner join 
    book_titles bt on bt.id = c.child_book_title_id
left join 
    book_title_names btn on btn.book_title_id = parent_book_title_id
left join 
    book_title_names btn2 on btn2.book_title_id = child_book_title_id
group by 
    c.parent_book_title_id
order by 
    c.parent_book_title_id asc
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions that can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be relying upon the `GROUP BY` and `MAX( )` to filter the results. It would be better to include a `WHERE` clause to ensure you get what you want.

Try this code:

```
select 
    c.child_book_title_id as 'child ID', 
    btn2.text 'Child Title',
    c.rank as 'Last Episode/Season Number',
    c.parent_book_title_id as 'parent ID',
    btn.text 'Parent Title'
from 
    container_associations c
inner join 
    book_titles bt on bt.id = c.child_book_title_id
left join 
    book_title_names btn on btn.book_title_id = parent_book_title_id
left join 
    book_title_names btn2 on btn2.book_title_id = child_book_title_id
where rank = (
  select max(rank)
  from container_associations c2
  where parent_book_title_id = c.parent_book_title_id)
order by 
    c.parent_book_title_id asc
```

I made a fiddle to try it out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d485f/1